# Firebase "addListenerForSingleValueEvent" keeps getting old values that no longer is in Firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I keep getting the old values (which no longer is in the database) from my Firebase database. Here is how the database looks right now:

[image]

I am getting the info under `friendlist`. It used to be only one child there with key-value set `soosk: true`, but now it looks like in the photo. When using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` to my `databaseRef`, the friendlist retrieved only has `soosk: true` in it. Here is my code:

```
mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase
                .getInstance()
                .getReference(
                        "users/"+FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()
                );

        mFirebaseDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                Log.d(TAG, user.getFriendlist().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Where are you setting the new value?

Comment: @AlexM. Directly in the Firebase console

Comment: And when you change the value, let's say for `chris` from `true` to `false`, when you display the data, is displayed `false`?

Comment: @AlexM. no it still does display "soosk: true" only

Comment: But i cannot see `soosk: true` in you database. Can you explain more?

Comment: @AlexM. First I added `soosk: true` to my database, then I run the app and it logged `soosk: true`. Then I removed `soosk: true` from my database, and added the three new childs as you can see in my photo above, but when I run the app again it still logs `soosk: true` and not the three new childs. But if I use `addValueEventListener()` then it updateds values when I re-run my app.

Comment: Even if I use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`, shouldn't it display the new values when app is re-run? @AlexM.

Comment: You need to use `addValueEventListener()` becase this method is checking for changes for every child in real time. If you use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`, as the name of the method says, it checks only for a single value.

Comment: @AlexM. But I only want to check once, on startup of my app?

Comment: `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` is checking for a single value. As i undersrtand you need to listen for more than one value so the only way is to use `addValueEventListener()`. One more mention, don't forget to use:
`yourReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);` in your `onDestroy` method.

Comment: Ok, I see, thanks a lot! If you want you can answer the question so I can upvote & accept the answer.

Comment: Just answerd. Glad to help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you need to use to have all the values updated is `addValueEventListener()`. Because you need to listen for more than one value this is the only way to achieve it and to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`.

The most important thing is to remove the `listener` in your `onDestroy` method like this:

```
yourReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
```